# SQL Script for Match Information

Tags: sql, sql-like

i just have a project on hand and my manager want us to write sql script that improve the database unmatched solution.
problem: customers type in various names for the same company so the database will show up a lot of unmatched information. our manager wants us to do the LIKE function for these information and pull out the information that will possibly match the companies in the database and show the existing contact information. can anyone give me a hint or explain the logic for me? thanks

Comment: You can use the Wildcard, but you don't tell us which database you're using.

Comment: SQL Server then Column1 LIKE '%'+Column2+'%'

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: There's also soundex, but either way you are going to miss stuff and generate false positives unless the silicon deity really likes you.

Comment: you can also look at any full text search functions that your database supports - for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Comment: A common solution to this problem is Levenshtein distance.  You can google it to find an implementation for your database.